# Android Separating two numbers with comma

Tags: java

At this moment my code separating like this 1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1 and i want to make this 11,22,12,21,11,11,11

my code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.one:
        //disp.append("1");

         list.add("1");

        break;
        case R.id.two:
            list.add("2");

    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : list) {
           sb.append(s);
           if (sb.length() > 0)
                 sb.append(",");
    }
    String returnedItems = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(returnedItems);
    disp.append(returnedItems);


}
```

any idea and help, im new in java and programming

Comment: I don't see the relationship between your current output and your wanted output.

Comment: Are you saying that you only want commas between every other ID...? Or are you giving us a fun riddle to try and figure out how 1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1 becomes 11,22,12,21,11,11,11?

Comment: I said im new, its possible i made a lot of mistakes, I even don't have idea how to separate, i just took code from other post and tried to make one ;//

Comment: i want to add comma after 2 numbers add, i mean if i press 11 it will add coma, if i press 21 for e.g. it will add coma again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `for (String s:list)` syntax, you can loop by index:

```
for (int n = 0; n < list.size(); ++ n) {
   String s = list.get(n);
   sb.append(s);
   ...
}
```

Now you have the index of the element available, and you can use that to determine when to insert commas, e.g.:

```
for (int n = 0; n < list.size(); ++ n) {
   String s = list.get(n);
   sb.append(s); 
   if (n % 2 == 1) // append a comma after odd elements
      sb.append(",");
}
```

Reworking that to keep the string from ending with a stray "," if `list` contains an even number of elements is left as an exercise (hint: think about inserting commas *before* even elements instead of after odd ones).

Comment: You may also wish to go over http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines about being specific in questions.